# How do you drag a link without its parent div attached?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have an image that is linked that is contained by a div. I want to be able to **drag the linked image** to a tinyMCE control without its surrounding DIV.

HTML:

```
<div id="image_preview"><a href="somelink"><img src="someimage" /></a></div>
```

For whatever reason it's dragging the DIV along with the IMG and A. Is there a way to get it to not drag the DIV. I've tried preventing default ondrag, onmousedown etc. on the DIV, but then nothing drags.

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image_preview').on('mousedown', function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#image_preview').on('dragstart', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and a couple of other things, but of course I knew none of those would do anything other than prevent dragging of anything within the DIV.

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code? specially what jquery commands you wrote

Comment: Do you only use jQuery or also jQuery UI?

Comment: sorry, I don't use jQuery UI. Was your suggestion going to be drag/clone?

Comment: As a quick solution to this problem I had to wrap the link in an element that does not drag by default, in this case a table/tr/td.

Comment: you could modify the dragged content, but this won't work in IE8 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Change your markup to this:

```
<div draggable="false"><a href="somelink" draggable="false"><img src="someimage" draggable="true" /></a></div>
```

You should be able to prevent IE's default dragging bahavior by using something like this:

```
document.ondragstart = function () { 
    return false; 
};
```

Comment: The draggable attribute is not compatible with IE until at least v9, which is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="image_preview"><a href="somelink"><img src="someimage" /></a></div>

    <div id="anotherdiv"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
        $( "img" ).draggable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).appendTo('#anotherdiv');
        }            
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not using jQuery UI. And it looks like everyone has missed the intended result which is dragging the 'linked' image, and not 'just' the image.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when making a drag & drop image pane to use alongside TinyMCE.  This solution worked for me using Firefox's native drag & drop: Instead of wrapping the img tag with a td, tr, etc. as mentioned above, I placed a tiny comment before the image:  .  This was enough for it to exclude the parent element in the drag & drop, which was a DIV.  I hope this helps someone!